# Hidden, un-cancellable local notifications on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, notifications, local, ios4

During app development, I created 2 local notifications that repeat every day (one in the morning and one in the evening). I am trying to cancel them (and all others) via a call to

```
[[UIApplication sharedInstance] cancelAllLocalNotifications]
```

but they are still occurring at the scheduled times. When I query for the list of scheduled notifications (via `[[UIApplication sharedInstance] scheduledLocalNotifications]`) the list is empty.

I am using the final release of OS4, and I submitted this as a bug to Apple already.

Has anyone else seen this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yea, it happened to me before with the notifications repeating every second!!!
Just reboot your phone and it'll be okay.